# Decoding a Roblox backdoor

Tags: lua, programming-languages, reverse-engineering, exploit, roblox

I am working on a Roblox lua script that I found when searching for backdoors into a game I moderate. The backdoor loaded an external script that I got the source code for and I am working on decoding and reverse engineering it.

The line that I am having trouble with is

```
local varname = #{6133}
```

This is really confusing me because I have never encountered it before. I do very little Lua programming but I am experience in Java and C++, but even after research I don't know what the #{number} does.

I have also ran into #{num1, num2, num3, etc.} but I suspect that does practically the same as the first line in this post.

If anyone can help me understand what the above does that would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{6133}` creates a sequence with one element: 6133. `#` is the length operator, which tells you how many elements are in a sequence. Putting them together, it becomes clear that `#{6133}` is just a complicated way of writing the number `1`.

Comment: You beat me to the answer!  See "Tables/Arrays": https://devhints.io/lua

Comment: Thank you both.  This exploit has a lot of those in it's obfuscation and that's really the only thing I did not understand. This clears a lot up for me thank you.